# What are the reliable and valid test to measure working memory?

Tags: measurement, music, short-term-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reliably measure working memory capacity?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-to-reliably-measure-working-memory-capacity)

I am currently doing my thesis on how different types of music affect the cognitive performance more specifically working memory in an individual.

Can anyone suggest reliable and valid test to measure working memory?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Hopefully, the existing question answers your question. If not, feel free to ask a separate question identifying the unique aspects of your question. All the best with your thesis and please feel welcome to ask other questions related to your thesis on this site.